# How can you match the doman and top level domain (example.com) using Regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to math all domain `example` and the extension `.com` (aka. top level domain) from a text that can include links but I fail completely as it matches the subdomain too and also things the domain is the extension sometimes.

Goal:

```
https://www.subdomain.example.com/folder/folder  -> example.com
example.com/folder/folder                        -> example.com
www.subdomain.example.com/folder/folder          -> example.com
example.com                                      -> example.com
www.example.com                                  -> example.com
subdomain.example.com                            -> example.com
```

Attempt 1:

```
(?:(?:www?).)?\b((xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,}\b
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2bgtSo/1)

Attempt 2:

```
(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?[\w/\-?=%.]+\.[\w/\-&?=%.]+
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iWvjhR/1)

Comment: Please add more examples, what do you mean by 'extension'?

Comment: @PoulBak, added more info in the post

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work or be a starter: https://regex101.com/r/1UMjML/1
(updated regex slightly)

regex: `(?<=https?://)(?:\w+\.)+(?<domain>\w+\.\w+)[/\s$]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this selects only links where there is http present and also adds / at the end. I want it to find all example.com basically.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to match anything followed by a tld:

```
\w+\.com
```

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/AtxJzU/1)

You can then make it more explicit by padding the beginning and end with whatever you want to match on e.g.:

```
(?:https:\/\/.*?)?(\w+\.com)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But this sugesstion selects the domain but not the top level domain

Comment: @Clone oh shoot i misread your question, easy fix though one sec

Comment: No worries :). I provided two demos with some URLS and cases

Comment: @Clone took a stab at a [more explicit version](https://regex101.com/r/e58RzG/1) the idea there is to match based on the last period in the url. That works but halfway through writing it i realized something like `foo.com/baz.png` would throw it off. Regardless should be a good springboard.